# Не работает pythonw.exe при работе с внешними файлами

Tags: python, sqlite

Обнаружил, что при использовании в коде ссылок на внешние файлы скрипт с расширением pyw не запускается. Например:

- `conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')` - не работает;
- `conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` - работает.

В первом случае скрипт можно запустить при помощи `python.exe`, но при этом под окном приложения будет отображаться "второе" консольное окно. То же самое при указании любых внешних путей. Например:

- `edit_ic = PhotoImage(file='img/edit-icon.gif')` - не работает.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему у вас не в разнице между `python.exe` и `pythonw.exe`, а в используемой рабочей директории. Пути у вас относительные (`data.db`, `img/edit-icon.gif`) поэтому если используется рабочая директория отлична от директории, где сохранён сам Питон скрипт, файлы не будут найдены.

Использовать [директорию, где лежит исходный код (`get_script_dir()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279), явно, чтобы абсолютный путь получить, или использовать [`pkg_resources.resource_string()`, `pkg_resources.resource_stream()`, чтобы неявно ресурсы получить (работает даже для файлов, упакованных в zip архив)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5356563/4279) *не лучший подход*, если ресурсы не только на чтение и если одна и та же инсталляция может быть использована разными пользователями.

Лучше использовать [`appdirs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs/), чтобы получить подходящие для платформы пути к директориям куда можно пользовательские данные записать:

```
>>> from appdirs import AppDirs
>>> dirs = AppDirs("SuperApp", "Acme")
>>> dirs.user_data_dir
'/Users/trentm/Library/Application Support/SuperApp'
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решил путем добавления функции поиска абсолютного пути файла:

```
def find_data_file(filename):
"""
Осуществляет поиск расположения внешних файлов приложения.
"""
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):  # Если прилажение упаковано
        data_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:  # Приложение не упаковано и нужно найти файл
        data_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(data_dir, filename)
```

http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1442709.html

Comment: `__file__` не всегда работает (например, если скрипт вызван используя `execfile()`), можно использовать `get_script_dir()` функцию, упомянутую в моём ответе, которая поддерживает и этот случай. Питон позволяет импортировать, запускать скрипты не распаковывая `zip`-архивы, поэтому просто использование абсолютного пути не поможет в общем случае (`pkg_resources` поддерижвает и `zip`-архивы). Если нужно сохранить пользовательские данные на диск, то [можно `appdirs` использовать, чтобы подходящую директорию получить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489023/23044)