# Абсолютный путь к модулю, который использует мою функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули, python-import

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая может получать абсолютный путь к файлу модуля, который её использует.

Если написать так:

```
import os
def foo():
    print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

То я буду получать путь только к файлу, в котором находится функция `foo`.

Comment: Что мешает в модуле, который вызывает `foo()`, использовать `__file__` напрямую? (или [любой другой способ найти путь к модулю](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)). И передать этот путь в ввиде параметра в `foo()`, если необходимо.

Comment: Именно так и решил сделать. Просто думал может есть что-то чего я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CPython, можно из стэка вызовов получить глобальные переменные вызывающего модуля:

```
import inspect
import os

def foo():
    caller_globals = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals
    return os.path.abspath(caller_globals['__file__'])
```

Это следует рассматривать как dirty hack и попытаться найти более подходящее решение в зависимости от конкретного случая, например, передать [путь к модулю (`get_script_dir()`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279) в качестве явного параметра в `foo()`, если необходимо. Или спросить зачем вообще явный путь нужен, может быть следует использовать `pkgutil.get_data`/[`pkg_resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279) или похожие инструменты, чтобы получить необходимые данные для приложения. Или возможно следует использовать [`appdirs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489023/23044), чтобы получить пути куда пользовательские данные можно положить.