# При вызове скрипта через символьную ссылку меняется рабочий каталог

Tags: python

Небольшой скрипт читает файл `list` , расположенный в директории со скриптом:

```
open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/list','w') as F
```

Делаю символьную ссылку:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/script/script.py /usr/local/bin/script
```

И при попытке обратится к скрипту через ссылку получаю:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/list'
```

Как правильно сослаться на файл **и** при этом сохранить переносимость?

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий каталог не меняется. Текущий рабочая директория для процесса не зависит ни от расположения ссылки ни от пути к исходному Питон-скрипту. Можно убедиться, вызвав `os.getcwd()`.

Поверхностную проблему с symlink—чтобы найти путь к скрипту в Питоне—можно решить, вызвав [`os.path.realpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath). Хотя решение, использующее `__file__`, может сломаться в общем случае и вместо `__file__` [можно использовать более универсальную `get_script_dir()` функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).

Более регулярным решением является использование `pkgutil.get_data()`/`pkg_resources`, чтобы найти ресурсы, установленные рядом с Питон-кодом или `appdirs` модуль, чтобы найти место куда данные приложения/пользователя можно положить. См. [Не работает pythonw.exe при работе с внешними файлами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/488546/23044)